# Switching videos using vimeo player

Tags: html, angular, vimeo, ionic5

i am implementing a vimeo video in my app using the below code:

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20oCD.png)

and

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.player1 = new Player(this.playerContainer.nativeElement);
  this.player1.on('play', function(data) {
    console.log('played the video!');
  });

  this.player1.on('pause', function(data) {
    console.log('paused the video!',data);
  });
}
```

The player and all its functions work until i pass a new link to the iframe, the video plays but it doesn't return when the video was paused or played, unless i reload the page - does anyone know how to fix this? The code for the vimeo player is in a component which is being called by the main page and a new link is passed to it when some item is pressed Also, i am using Ionic5 and Angular.

Comment: Maybe try [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mintplayer/ng-vimeo-player)